# find all solutions to a system of equation in a given range.

Tags: systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations, quadratics

I have a system of equations as follow:

> For $k,i,j=0,1,2,3,4..... $
>   $$1) k=3+18ij+11i+5j$$ 
>   $$2) k=5+18ij+13i+7j$$
>   $$3) k=16+18ij+17(i+j)$$ 
>   $$4) k=18ij+19i+19j+20$$

the $k$,$i$,$j$ all are integers .. 
I am interested in all $k$ in a given range where range always begins from 0 up to a known integer (say 1000). Evidently these equations may deliver the same $k$, i.e. we may get duplicates. here are two questions:
1-How could I count all such $k$ excluding repetitions?
2- is there a way to unite all four equations?

Thanks

Comment: These equations look a lot like they came from a sieve definition.  What is the problem source?  More specifically, they look like they are related to the twin primes sieve arising from $6k\pm 1=(6i\pm 1)(6j\pm 1)$...

Comment: @abiessu no, it is coincidental. I am working on a data pattern, I would like to find the number of unique $k$ that would correspond to these equations. but thanks for the hint, maybe after solving this I take a look at the twin problem.

Comment: That's quite a coincidence that it looks so similar to the twin primes.  Given the similarities, there is likely a way to condense into a single equation, but it may take some time.  I'll think about it for a bit and see what I can come up with.

Comment: I simplified and found two incompatible equations $6 i + 12 j = -13, \;6 i + 12 j = -15$

Comment: @Raffaele, $k,i,j$ are all integers, they can take 0 but no negative values. I don't know what you mean with simplification, but whatever you did does not serve the purpose. Remember, the target is to find the count of all $k$ that would fit the picture delivered by these 4 equations. I thought unifying the four equations may help us count the acceptable $k$s.

Comment: $k=3+18ij+11i+5j;\;k=5+18ij+13i+7j\to 3+18ij+11i+5j=5+18ij+13i+7j$
and simplifying $2i+2j=-2\to i+j=-1$ from the other two I get $k=16+18ij+17(i+j);\;k=18ij+19i+19j+20 \to 16+18ij+17i + 17j=18ij+19i+19j+20 $ and simplifying I get $2i+2j=-4\to i+j=-2$ and the two equations $i+j=-1;\;i+j=-2$ are not compatible. Which means that there are no solutions. I also verified numerically with *Mathematica*. There are no $(i,j)$  which verify the system

Comment: Nothing obvious is showing; I think you are stuck with just making a big list of all the outputs and picking the unique ones.

Comment: @Raffaele : the set of equations is not simultaneous.  The OP is looking for any $k$ satisfying any of the equations.

Answer (score 0):

The four equations might have a universal common equation they arise from.  The first two transform as follows:

$$
k=18ab+11a+5b+3\\
18k=18^2ab-7\cdot 18a+5\cdot 18b-36\\
18k+1=(18a+5)(18b-7)
$$

$$
k=18ab+13a+7b+5\\
18k=18^2ab-5\cdot 18a+7\cdot 18b-36\\
18k+1=(18a+7)(18b-5)
$$

These two come together to make

$$18k+1=(18a\pm 5)(18b\mp 7)$$

With the other two equations, we do some of the same processes and we get

$$18k+1=(18a\pm 1)(18b\pm 1)$$

The universal equation they come from is along the lines of

$$18k+1=(2a+1)(2b+1)$$

The problem with using this equation is that you get more results on the RHS than on the LHS.

The easy approach is to note that this set of numbers is the count of values of the form $18k+1$ which are not prime, and Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions can give a good approximation for the value.

To find the complete count of such results, you probably have to manually (with a program) count the set of $k$ results which are unique.  With no more than $k=1000$, it may even be possible to count all the $18k+1$ primes by hand.